# Localizing at maximal ideals and the product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $D$ be an integral domain, $M_{i}$, $i = 1,...,r$ be some of its mutually distinct maximal ideals, and $e_{i}$be positive integers for all $i$. Is it true in general that the extension of the product ideal $M_{1}^{e_{1}}\cdots M_{r}^{e_{r}}$ in the localized ring $D_{M_{1}}$ is the same as the extension of $M_{1}^{e_{1}}$ in $D_{M_{1}}$? (In short, coincide with $M_{1}^{e_{1}}D_{M_{1}}$ up to identification $D\leq D_{M_{1}}$?) 
If this type of statement is true with some additional conditions, would anyone give some precise statements and indications of proofs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Here are the basic facts used:

1. For any morphism $f\colon A\to B$ the extension of ideals $I \mapsto I^e$ (from ideals of $A$ to ideals of $B$) is a multiplicative operation, that is:
   $(I\cdot J)^e = I^e \cdot J^e$.
2. An ideal $I$ extends to the total ideal $1$ for the map $A \mapsto S^{-1} A$ if and only if $I \cap S \ne \emptyset$.
3. For the map $A\mapsto A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}' \ne \mathfrak{m}$ extends to $(1)$ ( since $\mathfrak{m}' \not \subset \mathfrak{m}$).

Comment: Would you mind explain the first basic fact with a little more detail? I haven't seen it before, and that's indeed the only nontrivial thing to me (although I know the commutativity with some other operations like intersections,...).

Comment: @Manan: $I^e$ is generated in $B$ by the elements $f(i)$, $i \in I$, and similarly for $J^e$. But in fact $I^e$ is generated by $f(s)$ where $s$ is a system of generators for $I$. Take $\{s\}$ a system of generators for $I$, $\{t\}$ for $J$ (easier to think in terms of system of generators). Then $I\cdot J$ generated by $\{s\cdot t\}$, and $I^e \cdot J^e$ generated by $\{f(s) \cdot f(t)\}$. And again, $(I\cdot J)^e$ generated by $\{f(s\cdot t) \}$. And now... $f(s\cdot t ) = f(s) \cdot f(t)$

Comment: Oh I got the point. I think I fully understood your answer. Thank you so much with your kind explanation!

Comment: You are welcome! Oh, by the way, Atiyah and Macdonald seems like a useful book.

Comment: Great! I have a copy of it, but somehow I haven't seriously looked on it yet. It seems like it's time for me to regret my fault and read that classic with care. Again, thanks for the advice!